# Not able to clear the Feeds in Notification feed

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

My aim is to clear the notification feed. I use the following to do so

```
userPrivateFeed.unfollow('PrivateMessageBoardFlat', groupId, { keepHistory: false });

userPrivateFeed.follow('PrivateMessageBoardFlat', groupId, {limit: 0});
```

However this is not working and when I query the userPrivateFeed, all the previous activities are fetched.

Also point to note is that prior to these calls, I mark them read and seen. But when I fetch the activities from the feed after the above calls, all of them are unread and unseen. That makes me think that the unfollow with keepHistory worked, but the follow with limit did not work.

Comment: I also tested with the value limit: 1 and that works as expected. Only 1 activity is copied.

When I use limit: -1, no activities are copied. Though I am not sure the repercussions of using non-documented -1

Comment: which client are you using?

Comment: js client for NodeJs

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue regarding limit 0 has been fixed by this [pull request](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js/pull/90)